# A plane crash riddle

Tags: riddle

A plane crashes in the middle of a desert, and every single person dies. But there are survivors, how is this possible?

Hint:

> You need to read very carefully!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple ...

> ... the married people survived.

Comment: Correct! Sorry was this too simple?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Actually I was expecting a similar version where the plane crashed on a border.

Comment: Yes, its similar i just made some tweaks to the original riddle.

Answer (score 2):

> If ever single person dies, The couple's did not die.